# How to get rid of extra parentheses, quotes or commas Python

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot and i'm running in issue with getting list values with out extra parentheses, quotes or commas.

here's the code:

```
#gets slots for page
    def listindexcheck(slot):
        if totalitemcount > slot + (page * 9):
            return slot + (page * 9)
        else:
            return 0

    if argument == 'show':
#message set up
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title='title',
            description='Here is your inventory',
            colour=discord.Colour.red())
        for i in range(9):
            embed.add_field(name=f"Slot ({listindexcheck(i+1)})", value=f'Dur: {str(item_dur[listindexcheck(i+1)])}\n'
                                                                        f'Mod: {str(item_mod[listindexcheck(i+1)])}\n'
                                                                        f'E.lvl: {str(item_level[listindexcheck(i+1)])}\n'
                                                                        f'*id:{str(item_ids[listindexcheck(i+1)])}*\n')
        embed.set_footer(text='page: ' + str(page+1))
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        print (type(str(item_ids[listindexcheck(i+1)])))
```

and here's [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q9yU.png)

Type of data before converting it to string is list

i tried to turn values to string type to get rid of at least the quotes but that didn't work

My question is is there a way to just get the values without doing anything extra to it?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe do `str(item_dur[listindexcheck(i+1)][0])` to get the first item of the tuple only.

Comment: @bubulledu93 this works perfectly, why tho? is it becouse data im getting is a tuple with only one value?
either way this is easyest way so far so if you could make it into an answer that would be nice and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, `item_dur[listindexcheck(i+1)`, `item_mod[listindexcheck(i+1)` `item_level[listindexcheck(i+1)` `item_ids[listindexcheck(i+1)` seem to be tuples with only one item inside. Why there is a comma inside the parenthesis ? It is because  [the comma makes the tuple and not the parenthesis](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-tuple-single-empty/#:%7E:text=source%3A%20tuple_single_empty.py-,Tuple%20parentheses%20are%20basically%20optional,a%20tuple%2C%20not%20the%20parentheses.).

Therefore, to not get parenthesis and comma when you print them, you can just get the first item of the tuple like this `item_dur[listindexcheck(i+1)][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

After you've turned it into a string you could use the replace() method to remove any extra pieces that you don't want in there. You would replace anything that you don't want in there with `''` to simply remove it from the string.

Here's some info on the replace() method: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp

Comment: Don’t I have to cast it to a variable first to do that? I’ll try it later

Comment: You may be able to add it into your code as an additional executable method, for example, print (type(str(item_ids[listindexcheck(i+1)]).replace("(").replace(")"))). But I'm not sure about that. If not you will have to make an additional variable yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.replace`, and it'll be better if you make a function for this like that:

```py
def delete_brackets(text: str):
    return text.replace(')', '').replace(')', '').replace(',', '')
embed.add_field(name=f"Slot ({listindexcheck(i+1)})", value=f'Dur: {delete_brackets(str(item_dur[listindexcheck(i+1)]))}\n'
                                                                        f'Mod: {delete_brackets(str(item_mod[listindexcheck(i+1)]))}\n'
                                                                        f'E.lvl: {delete_brackets(str(item_level[listindexcheck(i+1)]))}\n'
                                                                        f'*id:{delete_brackets(str(item_ids[listindexcheck(i+1)]))}*\n')
```

So this will work for you.